# Creating an asymmetric key inside SQL Server to access a DLL fails

Tags: sql-server

I need to access a DLL (C#) from a SQL Server trigger for one of our requirements. I have compiled the DLL and could load it in SQL Server space by using the `Create Assembly` command, and then create a trigger for it.

The I have set the database to be trust worthy by setting the `TRUSTWORTHY` flag ON.

```
ALTER DATABASE %DBName% SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

But after realizing that this is unsafe way of doing it, I have signed the DLL with a key (`.snk` file) and tried to create an asymmetric key and then create a login based on the key, for whom I can grand external access. Either without setting DB as trustworthy or unless I create a user who can access the DLL using the key, I cannot use the DLL because it performs a file access. Hence the DLL has to be loaded with an external access permission. But while doing the below query to create the asymmetric key, I am getting an error which follows the query

```
USE [master];
GO

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [ClrPermissionsKey]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'D:\Trigger\TriggerManager.dll'
```

Error message:

> Msg 15208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file does not exist or has invalid format.

The `.snk` file lies in the same path as the DLL. Requesting your help here.

If this is not the correct way of doing it, please suggest.

Comment: reading [**this**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2011/10/28/deploying-sql-clr-assembly-using-asymmetric-key/), does your `*.snk`file have the same name as the `*.dll`?

Answer (score 0):

For me on Windows 11, I solved this by granting NTFS permission "*Read & execute*" for the folder that contains the DLL to the user "*Everyone*".

Detailed solution:

1. I go to the folder that contains the DLL file (so for you it would be "D:\Trigger\")
2. Right-click the folder and select "**Properties**". A popup window appears "*Folder properties*".
3. Go to the tab "**Security**", click button "**Edit**". A popup window appears "*Permissions for Folder*".
4. Add the SQL service account (I cheated and just did "*Everyone*" because I don't know what my SQL service account is), and for the permissions to grant I check all of the boxes "**List folder contents**" and "**Read & execute**" and "**Read**".
5. In the same popup window "*Permissions for Folder*" I click button "**OK**", which closes that popup.
6. In popup window "*Folder Properties*" I click button "**OK**" to save and close this popup.
7. Then I re-run the SQL query and it worked for me.

Credit: https://dbtut.com/index.php/2019/01/17/the-certificate-asymmetric-key-or-private-key-file-is-not-valid-or-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permissions-for-it/